# filling multidimensional array with dataframe of various dimensions

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, dataframe

I'm trying to keep many data frames of varying dimensions in a single multidimensional array. I can do this if all of the data frames have the same dimensions by first creating the array and filling it in with the data. But in this case, the data frames can vary in the number of rows they can have. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want them in a single array? Have you considered storing them in a list?

Comment: I haven't, but I assume that would also work for what I'm doing

Comment: To add _all_ data frames (that exist in the global environment) to a list, you could do: `df.list <- lapply(na.omit(sapply(ls(), function(x) ifelse(class(get(x)) == 'data.frame', x, NA))), function(x) get(x))`.

Comment: To do it manually, or for few data frames, just create a list like so: `df.list <- list(df1, df2, df3, etc.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is probably "you shouldn't be using an array for this". If you want to be able to store all the data frames in one object, you probably want a list - in fact, if you're reading them in immediately *before* this step, I'd suggest just

```
list_of_data_frames <- lapply(filelist,read.delim)
```

This is one of those situations where an explanation of what comes next is really needed for a substantive answer, though.

Really, and I'd emphasise this again, you probably don't want an array - not if you're dealing with data frames. An array is really just a vector with tightly associated metadata; while you can mutate it to convert it out into a data frame, or, well, really anything else, doing so is a pain. I've encountered a grand total of one operation that was well-served by turning a data frame into an array, and it was an improbable operation (composite image generation).